# HorizontalScrollView or Carrousel?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-imageview

I want to create a `HorizontalScrollView`, but with some "effects" in it, like this [example](http://25.media.tumblr.com/0a46e97269c9b8a269f5df1c2e813556/tumblr_melwhjYQby1r6rtzuo6_r1_1280.png), or this [other example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6DNt.jpg). The thing is that I don't know how many items I'll have to use; I get the `ImageView` from an API so it should be dynamic. How can I make that effect that if it's selected it becomes bigger with the `TextView` below? The closest example I found on SO is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310390/how-to-create-horizontal-scrollview-with-zoom-on-selected-item). That's exactly what I need, but I've tested the answer given and it doesn't work for me ... but the image from the question is exactly what I want. Can anyone guide me to do this?

Let's say I'll test it with 5 `ImageView` **ONLY FOR TESTING**, so an example to how to add those `ImageView` dynamically would be good for me as well.

Another example would be [Snapchat APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITnTG.png) but the difference is that I would like to add some effect on the selected like make it bigger or something.

### EDIT

I would like to get an example to how to do like a custom HorizontalScrollView with a Layout (adapter) and the most important if it's possible add an efect to the clicked one, and I want the adapter because I'll need to get the item clicked of course. The thing that I think I should use a RecycleView as @UncaughtException said to me because I don't know how much images I'll get and I'll have to put on my APP so I think this is the solution.

It would be a mix between [Snapchat HoritzontalScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITnTG.png) and [This image from a SO question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snB84.png)

Comment: which solution would like to implement? The one on the stackoverflow's question or the one in *other example* lins

Comment: @Blackbelt I meant the image posted on the question.

Comment: that's  achievable with a ViewPager.

Comment: So when I select one of those ImageViews it would be bigger than the rest ? I could do that with ViewPager?

Comment: it will not happen automatically and it is not probably the best way to implement it, but it is possible

Comment: I want to become bigger to let the user know that what's the imageview selected.... that's why I thought [this](http://25.media.tumblr.com/0a46e97269c9b8a269f5df1c2e813556/tumblr_melwhjYQby1r6rtzuo6_r1_1280.png) or  [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/snB84.png) would be good...

Comment: use a scrollview  and animate  (scale) the clicked image on click.

Comment: @Tasos could you give me a sample or any guide to do this?

Comment: you should use a horizontal recyclerview to get that. [example](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview)

Comment: @UncaughtException Thanks for your advice, but I think I don't want that effect, but this I'll mark as a favorite since I was looking for this exact library :D

Comment: Lookin for a answer more detailed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Display the images horizontally in a [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

**Step 2:**

Apply the [`ScaleAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html) class to the clicked item to zoom in on it. This can be done in the `instantiateItem()` method of the `ViewPager`'s `PagerAdapter`.

Also, there are some ready-to-use open source widgets available like [`CoverFlow`](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow) and [`FancyCoverFlow`](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow). You might want to check out the source code to see how they work.

**EDIT:**

Firstly, regarding your question of how to handle an unknown number of images, you should realize that in all such widgets (`ListView`, `GridView`, `ViewPager` etc.), the number of objects coming from the API is always unknown at first, i.e. it becomes known when then API response is received. So if you first implement a `ViewPager` in the normal way, you will see how this is handled. Basically you have to use an `Adapter` and a model object to populate the `ViewPager` or `ListView`. The API response will be either JSON or XML, and after parsing it, you will know the exact number of items.

So I think you should start with first implementing a `ViewPager` in the normal way. There are any number of examples available for this. Two interesting ones are [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9089380/3287204) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13860832/3287204). They are interesting for your case because they also contain example code of how to enlarge the image.

Now coming to the second problem: how do we enlarge the image. To do this, one way is to use the `ScaleAnimation` class. For example, say you want to enlarge an image by 100% around its center:

```
ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation =  new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 1.5f,
                                                    1.0f, 1.5f,
                                                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                                                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

scaleAnimation.setDuration(200);
scaleAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

imageView.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

I would use this code on the image in the `instantiateItem()` method of the `ViewPager`'s `PagerAdapter`. This should work. Or you can try the zoom animation approach in one of the two previous examples.

I'm afraid you'll have to try to create a working project using these examples as a guide. Then we can further discuss any other problems you face. I'm sure that this can be done quite easily, and I know you can do it. Best ...

**EDIT 2:**

As per the two examples that you have given, have you seen [this](https://code.google.com/p/carousel-layout-android/) and [this](https://github.com/mrleolink/SimpleInfiniteCarousel)? Is that what you're looking for ? And does it bring you any closer to solving the problem ?

Comment: I saw the [CoverFlow](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow) allready, but do you know if I could do this using something like this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/snB84.png)?

Comment: I have given the approach above ... if you apply it correctly then I'm sure it will work ... :)

Comment: And do you know if I could use [FancyCoverFlow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow) with those images not rotated? I mean those images are like turned I want it without rotation

Comment: You can study the source code of those libraries and modify it to suit your own needs ... :)

Comment: So what shall I use to display the imageviews RecycleView, GridView, ListView, ViewPager...?

Comment: Isn't `ViewPager` what you need to use here ??

Comment: Thats what I don't know whats the best solution there's people told to me that the best solution is use recycleview and then put in on a Horitzontalsxrollview and for example you saying that use a viewpager I really don't care about what to use I only want it to look like those 2 examples on my edit

Comment: My guess is you can use either `HorizontalScrollView` or `ViewPager`, and then add the zoom effect. Please also see the edit, might be helpful ... :)

Answer (score 7):

In your case definitely you can use `ViewPager`, but if i were you i would go for `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayoutManager` with its orientation set to `Horizontal`, so you will not need an `HorizontalScrollView`, and using `RecyclerView` you will also get the `adapter` thing you are looking for..

Now in order to `scale` or show some other effect on `click` to differentiate it from others, you can `Animate` that particular view,

I have written some demo code for that , posting here the required files , let me know if this is what you want,

**Activity**

```
/**
  * Created by Satyen on 10/27/15.
  **/
public class SlidingDrawerActivity extends Activity {

   RecyclerView rcyList;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_scroll_list);

        rcyList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcyList);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        rcyList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

       /* rcyList.addItemDecoration(
                new DividerItemDecoration(this, null));*/
        MyRecyclerViewAdapter myRecyclerAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this);
        rcyList.setAdapter(myRecyclerAdapter);

    }


}
```

**Activity Layout**

```
<!-- layout_scroll_list.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcyList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp" />

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Adapter**

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
View animatedView = null;

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, final int i) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);


    CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
    /*final Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.scale_up);*/
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // You can tweak with the effects here
            if (animatedView == null) {
                animatedView = view;
            } else {
                animatedView.setAnimation(null);
                animatedView = view;
            }
            ScaleAnimation fade_in = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 1.3f, 1f, 1.3f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            fade_in.setDuration(100);     // animation duration in milliseconds
            fade_in.setFillAfter(true);    // If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it is finished.
            view.startAnimation(fade_in);
        }
    });
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {
    //Setting text view title
    customViewHolder.textView.setText("Data No. " + i);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 10;
}

public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected ImageView imageView;
    protected TextView textView;

    public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        this.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }
}
}
```

**Adapter Row Layout**

```
<!-- list_row.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="dafdafda"
        android:textColor="#222"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Other than you can also use `TwoWayView` that gives the functionality of implementing `HorizontalListView`,

Above is just some demo code which may require some tweaks, let me know if this helps or ask further ...

Also adding the screenshots of the output ..

[image: Layout when none of the item is clicked]

[image: Layout when second item is clicked]

Comment: How should I use those icons, I mean this is a call from an API so I'll need to fill it as it needs, you got me?

Comment: Another thing, do you know why if I select one Data no. X and I scroll horizontally and I get back to it it's without zoom?

Comment: you mean showing them from url right ? If i am not wrong then you can use `ImageLoading` libraries like `UniversalImageLoader` and `Picasso` and in the `onBindViewHolder()` method you can update the images accordinly

Comment: Nono, I mean how to add it on the RecyclerView I used to do this on a ListView witch I had to do something like mListview.add(Image,Text);

Comment: Yes it is because of the view recycling, each time we scroll and come back the `onCreateViewHolder()` will be called so it loses the zoom let me see what i can do about that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93496/discussion-between-satyen-udeshi-and-skizo).

Comment: Hello mate, I'm facing with a similar problem let me know if you can help me out, I guess it's almost the same problem on here, but data is taken from `Firebase`, but I guess it doesn't matter, if you have any moment to help me I'll be glad this is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010917/custom-adapter-for-firebaseadapter), The thing i'm trying is to create something like this : [Image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoodieBag/CarouselPicker/master/gif/gif_image_480.gif), but it's giving me problems with FirebaseAdapter... if it'd be a Recyclerview it'd work I guess...